# How to execute the query [select 'I'm Looking for study guides 1Z0-071, 1Z0-146, 1Z0-148!' from dual]?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to write a query, but I get an error:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu May 24 11:24:48 2018
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select 'I'm Looking for study guides 1Z0-071, 1Z0-146, 1Z0-148!' from dual;
```

> ERROR:
>       ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Comment: I removed second part of your question (asking for study guide - it's offtopic on SO). I suggest to use search engine(a lot of books and courses available ).

Comment: I understood everything, thank you! Topic is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`quoting string literal`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617):

[image]

```
select q'{I'm Looking for study guides 1Z0-071, 1Z0-146, 1Z0-148!}'
from dual;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=750df6e24c4fe3c6f4bb0ff6df46d191)**

This mechanism is really useful especially when generating a lot of dynamic SQL and allows to avoid all clunky `'''''`.